# A question about discord embed descriptions (i am using Java discord library)

Tags: discord-jda

I want to make multiple spaces in discord embed descriptions, here is my code:

```
embedBuilder.setColor(Color.darkGray);
embedBuilder.setDescription("blah       blah");
event.getChannel().sendMessage(embedBuilder.build()).queue();
```

But when I look at the output in the discord server. It says:
`blah blah`

But what I really want is a: `blah (multiple spaces) blah`

Answer (score 0):

try using `\t` instead of the many spaces. It would look like this:

```
embedBuilder.setColor(Color.darkGray);
embedBuilder.setDescription("blah\tblah");
event.getChannel().sendMessage(embedBuilder.build()).queue();
```

I also have a website for you that simplifies working with embeds: 
[Discohook | Embed Generator](https://discohook.org/?message=eyJtZXNzYWdlIjp7fX0)